# Error in Tableau calculated field formula

Tags: tableau-api

I have a bar chart and displaying Absorption figure. Everything up to 2018 is correct. However we are now in Q1 and for 2018 it should not sum all just get data for March.

Currently it is`SUM([AbsorptionCalc])`.

I'm thinking of changing to:
Not sure if my logic is correct?

```
if YEAR(datePeriod)= Year(getdate()) 
then [Calc]
else SUM([Calc])
end
```

Errors:

```
1) I don't think I use getdate

2) "Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate comparisons or results in 'if' expressions"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, as stated in the error.

Create new field -**New_AbsorbCal** as below

```
IF YEAR(datePeriod)= Year(getdate()) 
then [Calc]
END
```

Then to sum the the above calculated field drag and drop on the shelf and sum it there.

```
SUM([New_AbsorbCal])
```